# Контекстное/всплывающее меню в Android

Tags: java, android, popup

Есть ли техническая возможность сделать приложение, добавляющее свое контекстное или всплывающее меню в любом месте системы?
Хочу, чтобы при выделении любого текста появлялась дополнительная кнопка

Comment: Здесь создается меню только в приложении, насколько я понимаю. А мне нужно, чтобы мое контекстное меню появлялось, например, в браузере

Comment: @TITAN Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.